# What is the difference of using URL::asset() and asset()?

Tags: laravel

I'm learning Laravel and want to understand it better. What is the difference of using `URL::asset()` and `asset()`?

Also what are the parts in front of the :: called?

Comment: The part in front of the :: are your classes

Comment: Where can I get a list of the classes that I can use?

Comment: This isn't so bad, http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/

Comment: Thanks! One more question, do you know what the difference is between URL::asset() and asset()?

Comment: Made an answer out of it

Answer (score 1):

Both of the functions are, the same. `asset()` is simply **a helper function**. Specifically, helpers are more appropriate for views. It's a preference thing.

The part before the `::` is the class you are calling.

**Generate a URL for an asset:**

```
asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

Does the same as

```
URL::asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

Here you can read more about it: [Laravel helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls)

Answer (score 1):

Actually `asset()` is a helper function which calls `asset()` method from the `URL` class, you can find that helper file (`helpers.php`) inside `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support` folder  and the function looks something like this (Version-4.2):

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

There are other helper functions available in this file and  those functions are very useful to use as shortcut ((less typing)) but behind the scene, when you call any helper function `Laravel` will call the original `method` from the `class`. You may also check the [online documentation about helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers).